# Created SVG is too small and does not fit next to the Website name

Tags: html, css, xml, navbar

I have a simple logo which is in SVG format and I would like to add it to my website. Along with that I would like to display the website name also very next to it. The program I am facing is that the SVG logo is too small and it looks like a `.` next to the name of the website.

How can I make modification to SVG logo so it fits the same height as the Website name and displays properly next to the website name without lot of space or margin?

I tried making modification to `height`, `width` and `ViewPoint` but unable to find the right balance which can make it look good. Can someone please suggest to me what parameter should I make change so I can get the nice logo.

Following is my SVG:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>

<svg
   version="1.1"
   width="210mm"
   height="297mm"
   id="svg2"
   xml:space="preserve"
   inkscape:version="1.1 (c4e8f9e, 2021-05-24)"
   sodipodi:docname="Logo_draft.svg"
   viewBox="0 0 744.09449 1052.3623"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"><sodipodi:namedview
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1"
     objecttolerance="10"
     gridtolerance="10"
     guidetolerance="10"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:window-width="2120"
     inkscape:window-height="1113"
     id="namedview13"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:zoom="0.84951741"
     inkscape:cx="127.131"
     inkscape:cy="323.12463"
     inkscape:window-x="1555"
     inkscape:window-y="83"
     inkscape:window-maximized="0"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer2"
     fit-margin-top="0"
     fit-margin-left="0"
     fit-margin-right="0"
     fit-margin-bottom="0"
     units="mm"
     inkscape:document-units="px"
     inkscape:pagecheckerboard="0" /><metadata
     id="metadata8"><rdf:RDF><cc:Work
         rdf:about=""><dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format><dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" /></cc:Work></rdf:RDF></metadata><defs
     id="defs6"><linearGradient
       id="linearGradient3114"><stop
         id="stop3116"
         offset="0"
         style="stop-color:#3c6ee6;stop-opacity:1;" /><stop
         style="stop-color:#2b6aa6;stop-opacity:1;"
         offset="0.61536932"
         id="stop3118" /><stop
         style="stop-color:#0b4a86;stop-opacity:1;"
         offset="0.7922883"
         id="stop3120" /><stop
         id="stop3122"
         offset="1"
         style="stop-color:#064580;stop-opacity:1;" /></linearGradient><clipPath
       id="clipPath18"><path
         id="path20"
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
         d="M 0,0 V 2.73047 H 2.73047 V 0 H 0" /></clipPath><radialGradient
       inkscape:collect="always"
       xlink:href="#linearGradient4791"
       id="radialGradient4797"
       cx="740.57935"
       cy="-852.92871"
       fx="675.52924"
       fy="-1087.2935"
       r="434.55649"
       gradientTransform="matrix(1.7360202,-0.37809964,0.28591454,1.2524098,-331.27417,486.31408)"
       gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" /><filter
       inkscape:collect="always"
       id="filter3979"
       style="color-interpolation-filters:sRGB"
       x="-0.015898918"
       y="-0.015898242"
       width="1.0317978"
       height="1.0317965"><feGaussianBlur
         inkscape:collect="always"
         stdDeviation="4.9346659"
         id="feGaussianBlur3981" /></filter><radialGradient
       inkscape:collect="always"
       xlink:href="#linearGradient3114"
       id="radialGradient4011"
       gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
       gradientTransform="matrix(0.15755117,-0.04491593,0.03295755,0.1156049,-1280.3555,57.571863)"
       spreadMethod="repeat"
       cx="849.24457"
       cy="-889.59619"
       fx="812.67682"
       fy="-1102.9368"
       r="434.55649" /></defs><g
     transform="translate(1286.5947,194.25082)"
     style="display:inline"
     inkscape:label="Lenses"
     id="layer2"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"><path
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
       id="path3965"
       d="m 1323.0207,-1633.7307 c -174.903,18.5791 -313.894,157.5671 -332.4686,332.4688 h 291.8125 c 8.7366,-17.5843 23.0738,-31.9088 40.6561,-40.6563 z m 80,0 v 291.8437 c 17.5764,8.7404 31.8856,23.0459 40.625,40.6251 h 291.8123 c -18.5756,-174.912 -157.5234,-313.9028 -332.4373,-332.4688 z m -412.4686,412.4688 c 18.5612,174.9155 157.5566,313.89144 332.4686,332.46874 v -291.84374 c -17.5856,-8.7372 -31.9205,-23.0359 -40.6561,-40.625 z m 453.0936,0 c -8.7366,17.5871 -23.0486,31.8872 -40.625,40.625 v 291.84374 c 174.9226,-18.5642 313.8746,-157.54294 332.4373,-332.46874 z"
       style="display:inline;fill:#333333;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none;filter:url(#filter3979)"
       transform="matrix(0.10482879,0,0,0.10482879,-1306.587,53.007273)" /><path
       style="fill:url(#radialGradient4011);fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.0915312px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
       d="m -1168.6301,-118.98855 c -18.3349,1.94763 -32.9051,16.51757 -34.8523,34.852314 h 30.5904 c 0.9158,-1.84334 2.4188,-3.34496 4.2619,-4.26195 z m 8.3863,0 v 30.593634 c 1.8425,0.91624 3.3425,2.41587 4.2587,4.25868 h 30.5903 c -1.9473,-18.335824 -16.513,-32.906064 -34.849,-34.852314 z m -43.2386,43.238613 c 1.9458,18.33618 16.5165,32.904858 34.8523,34.852298 v -30.593628 c -1.8435,-0.91591 -3.3462,-2.41482 -4.2619,-4.25867 z m 47.4973,0 c -0.9159,1.84364 -2.4162,3.3427 -4.2587,4.25867 v 30.593628 c 18.3369,-1.94606 32.9031,-16.515038 34.849,-34.852298 z"
       id="path3124"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
       inkscape:export-filename="/data/text4139.png"
       inkscape:export-xdpi="15.98"
       inkscape:export-ydpi="15.98" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: To start with remove the height and width

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks a lot for the quick response. I tried as you mentioned but does not seem to make much difference as the SVG still appears as a `.` next to the Website text name. Is there anything further I can try?

Comment: There is a huge proportion of the SVG that is empty/white - is that intentional?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius Thanks a lot for your response. I do not have a detailed understanding of the SVG code actually. But if they are not adding any value we can remove them. It has been created using the tool `inkscape` by another colleague maybe it got added by default during the creation.

Comment: There is a lot in the SVG that probably does something but I have no idea what. Is this logo animated in some manner ? I copied this SVG and recreated in Illustrator, resized and saved as a square format svg with very little blank space if you are interested... much of the original `inkscape` markup is not present though

Answer (score 0):

Just edited the original svg in Illustrator in the hope that the newer version of your logo is more in keeping with the size you expect...

```css
svg{
border:1px solid red
}
```

```html
<h2>The original</h2>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   version="1.1"
   id="svg2"
   xml:space="preserve"
   inkscape:version="1.1 (c4e8f9e, 2021-05-24)"
   sodipodi:docname="Logo_draft.svg"
   viewBox="0 0 744.09449 1052.3623"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"><sodipodi:namedview
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1"
     objecttolerance="10"
     gridtolerance="10"
     guidetolerance="10"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:window-width="2120"
     inkscape:window-height="1113"
     id="namedview13"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:zoom="0.84951741"
     inkscape:cx="127.131"
     inkscape:cy="323.12463"
     inkscape:window-x="1555"
     inkscape:window-y="83"
     inkscape:window-maximized="0"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer2"
     fit-margin-top="0"
     fit-margin-left="0"
     fit-margin-right="0"
     fit-margin-bottom="0"
     units="mm"
     inkscape:document-units="px"
     inkscape:pagecheckerboard="0" /><metadata
     id="metadata8"><rdf:RDF><cc:Work
         rdf:about=""><dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format><dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" /></cc:Work></rdf:RDF></metadata><defs
     id="defs6"><linearGradient
       id="linearGradient3114"><stop
         id="stop3116"
         offset="0"
         style="stop-color:#3c6ee6;stop-opacity:1;" /><stop
         style="stop-color:#2b6aa6;stop-opacity:1;"
         offset="0.61536932"
         id="stop3118" /><stop
         style="stop-color:#0b4a86;stop-opacity:1;"
         offset="0.7922883"
         id="stop3120" /><stop
         id="stop3122"
         offset="1"
         style="stop-color:#064580;stop-opacity:1;" /></linearGradient><clipPath
       id="clipPath18"><path
         id="path20"
         inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
         d="M 0,0 V 2.73047 H 2.73047 V 0 H 0" /></clipPath><radialGradient
       inkscape:collect="always"
       xlink:href="#linearGradient4791"
       id="radialGradient4797"
       cx="740.57935"
       cy="-852.92871"
       fx="675.52924"
       fy="-1087.2935"
       r="434.55649"
       gradientTransform="matrix(1.7360202,-0.37809964,0.28591454,1.2524098,-331.27417,486.31408)"
       gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" /><filter
       inkscape:collect="always"
       id="filter3979"
       style="color-interpolation-filters:sRGB"
       x="-0.015898918"
       y="-0.015898242"
       width="1.0317978"
       height="1.0317965"><feGaussianBlur
         inkscape:collect="always"
         stdDeviation="4.9346659"
         id="feGaussianBlur3981" /></filter><radialGradient
       inkscape:collect="always"
       xlink:href="#linearGradient3114"
       id="radialGradient4011"
       gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
       gradientTransform="matrix(0.15755117,-0.04491593,0.03295755,0.1156049,-1280.3555,57.571863)"
       spreadMethod="repeat"
       cx="849.24457"
       cy="-889.59619"
       fx="812.67682"
       fy="-1102.9368"
       r="434.55649" /></defs><g
     transform="translate(1286.5947,194.25082)"
     style="display:inline"
     inkscape:label="Lenses"
     id="layer2"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"><path
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
       id="path3965"
       d="m 1323.0207,-1633.7307 c -174.903,18.5791 -313.894,157.5671 -332.4686,332.4688 h 291.8125 c 8.7366,-17.5843 23.0738,-31.9088 40.6561,-40.6563 z m 80,0 v 291.8437 c 17.5764,8.7404 31.8856,23.0459 40.625,40.6251 h 291.8123 c -18.5756,-174.912 -157.5234,-313.9028 -332.4373,-332.4688 z m -412.4686,412.4688 c 18.5612,174.9155 157.5566,313.89144 332.4686,332.46874 v -291.84374 c -17.5856,-8.7372 -31.9205,-23.0359 -40.6561,-40.625 z m 453.0936,0 c -8.7366,17.5871 -23.0486,31.8872 -40.625,40.625 v 291.84374 c 174.9226,-18.5642 313.8746,-157.54294 332.4373,-332.46874 z"
       style="display:inline;fill:#333333;fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:none;filter:url(#filter3979)"
       transform="matrix(0.10482879,0,0,0.10482879,-1306.587,53.007273)" /><path
       style="fill:url(#radialGradient4011);fill-opacity:1;fill-rule:nonzero;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.0915312px;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-opacity:1"
       d="m -1168.6301,-118.98855 c -18.3349,1.94763 -32.9051,16.51757 -34.8523,34.852314 h 30.5904 c 0.9158,-1.84334 2.4188,-3.34496 4.2619,-4.26195 z m 8.3863,0 v 30.593634 c 1.8425,0.91624 3.3425,2.41587 4.2587,4.25868 h 30.5903 c -1.9473,-18.335824 -16.513,-32.906064 -34.849,-34.852314 z m -43.2386,43.238613 c 1.9458,18.33618 16.5165,32.904858 34.8523,34.852298 v -30.593628 c -1.8435,-0.91591 -3.3462,-2.41482 -4.2619,-4.25867 z m 47.4973,0 c -0.9159,1.84364 -2.4162,3.3427 -4.2587,4.25867 v 30.593628 c 18.3369,-1.94606 32.9031,-16.515038 34.849,-34.852298 z"
       id="path3124"
       inkscape:connector-curvature="0"
       inkscape:export-filename="/data/text4139.png"
       inkscape:export-xdpi="15.98"
       inkscape:export-ydpi="15.98" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

And a modified version

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid blue
}
```

```html
<h2>re-fudged in Illustrator version</h2>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="250px" height="250px" viewBox="0 0 250 250" enable-background="new 0 0 250 250" xml:space="preserve">
    <g id="layer2" transform="translate(1286.5947,194.25082)" inkscape:groupmode="layer" inkscape:label="Lenses">
        <path id="path3965" inkscape:connector-curvature="0" fill="#333333" d="M-1173.803-189.05
            c-56.813,6.035-101.962,51.184-107.997,107.997h94.792c2.841-5.705,7.501-10.365,13.206-13.206V-189.05z M-1147.814-189.05v94.807
            c5.71,2.833,10.357,7.486,13.199,13.19h94.793C-1045.859-137.873-1090.993-183.023-1147.814-189.05z M-1281.8-55.064
            c6.027,56.821,51.175,101.962,107.997,107.999v-94.801c-5.713-2.841-10.365-7.481-13.206-13.198H-1281.8z M-1134.615-55.064
            c-2.842,5.717-7.489,10.357-13.199,13.198v94.801c56.821-6.028,101.962-51.178,107.992-107.999H-1134.615z"/>
        
        <radialGradient id="path3124_1_" cx="1135.7129" cy="-5179.2236" r="3542.8374" fx="837.5844" fy="-6918.5396" gradientTransform="matrix(0.0599 -0.0171 -0.0125 -0.0439 -1331.4193 -289.2803)" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
            <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#4C6DB4"/>
            <stop  offset="0.6154" style="stop-color:#2C6BA7"/>
            <stop  offset="0.7923" style="stop-color:#104B86"/>
            <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#16477F"/>
        </radialGradient>
        
        <path id="path3124" inkscape:export-ydpi="15.98" inkscape:export-xdpi="15.98" inkscape:export-filename="/data/text4139.png" inkscape:connector-curvature="0" fill="url(#path3124_1_)" stroke="#010101" stroke-width="0.0915" d="
            M-1176.078-191.327c-56.813,6.035-101.965,51.187-108,108h94.801c2.832-5.71,7.489-10.358,13.199-13.199V-191.327z
             M-1150.09-191.327v94.808c5.717,2.84,10.357,7.482,13.199,13.192h94.791C-1048.135-140.141-1093.27-185.293-1150.09-191.327
            L-1150.09-191.327z M-1284.078-57.333c6.027,56.813,51.187,101.964,108,107.999V-44.14c-5.71-2.835-10.367-7.482-13.199-13.192
            H-1284.078z M-1136.891-57.333c-2.834,5.71-7.482,10.357-13.199,13.192v94.807c56.828-6.035,101.962-51.178,107.99-107.999
            H-1136.891z"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```